# Load external script using javascript, but in bottom of body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using this script (Mobile ESP) in my website to detect whether users access it from mobile or desktop, and within it I dynamically load the scripts and css stylesheets I would need for each type of navigation (mobile or desktop).

My issue is that I would need to load a script that should be placed in the bottom of the body tag or it won't work. Is there a way to do that?

```
<head>
```

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    if (MobileEsp.isTierIphone || MobileEsp.isTierTablet || MobileEsp.isMobilePhone) {
        var cssUrl = "css/mobilePortraitStyle.css";
            $(document.head).append(
              $("<link/>")
              .attr({
                rel:  "stylesheet",
                type: "text/css",
                media: "screen and (orientation:portrait)",
                href: cssUrl
              })
            );
        var cssUrl = "css/mobileLandscapeStyle.css";
            $(document.head).append(
              $("<link/>")
              .attr({
                rel:  "stylesheet",
                type: "text/css",
                media: "screen and (orientation:landscape)",
                href: cssUrl
              })
            );
    } 

    else {
        var cssUrl = "css/desktopStyle.css";
            $(document.head).append(
              $("<link/>")
              .attr({
                rel:  "stylesheet",
                type: "text/css",
                href: cssUrl
              })
            );
        var jsUrl = "js/skrollr.min.js";
            $(document.head).append(
              $("<script/>")
              .attr({
                src: jsUrl
              })
            );
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: you can place the script at the end of body tag.

Answer (score 0):

try this, this will append the scripts to your end of the body tag

```
function loadjscssfile(filename, filetype){
 if (filetype=="js"){ //if filename is a external JavaScript file
  var fileref=document.createElement('script')
  fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
  fileref.setAttribute("src", filename)
 }
 else if (filetype=="css"){ //if filename is an external CSS file
  var fileref=document.createElement("link")
  fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
  fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
  fileref.setAttribute("href", filename)
 }
 if (typeof fileref!="undefined")
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(fileref)
}
```

call it using

```
loadjscssfile("myscript.js", "js") //dynamically load and add this .js file
loadjscssfile("mystyle.css", "css") ////dynamically load and add this .css file
```

**add this at the after body tag**